# Image Upload in zend form

Tags: file, zend-framework, upload

I am unable to upload image in zend form and also unable to save image in database.please help me and forward code

Comment: @Nandan: Welcome to SO. As you can see from the comments and downvotes, SO questions usually require a more specific description of the problem and a more narrow request for information. A general request like this with little evidence that you have taken the initial steps yourself will usually be viewed negatively. Check out the [FAQ])(http://stackoverflow.com/faq). On the other hand, for well-formulated questions, I think you'll find SO to be a great community and resource. Again, welcome to SO.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function getLogoForm()
{
    //Create Form
    $form = new Zend_Form();
    $form->setAction('logoupdate');
    $form->setMethod('post');
    $form->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
    $form->setAttrib('sitename', 'hostname');

    $logo = new Zend_Form_Element_File('logo');
    $logo->setDecorators(array('File',
            array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),
            array('Label', array('tag' => 'td')),
            array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr'))
    ));
    $logo->setLabel('Logo (png) ');
    $logo->setRequired(true);
    $logo->setDestination('includes/images/logo/');
    $logo->addValidator('Count', false, 1);
    $logo->addValidator('Extension', false, 'png');

    $form->addElement($logo);

    //Create a submit button.
    $form->addElement('submit', 'submit');
    $submitElement = $form->getElement('submit');
    $submitElement->setAttrib('class',"button");
    $submitElement->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper',
            'Description',
            'Errors', array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td',
                'colspan'=>'2','align'=>'right')),
            array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr'))
    ));
    $submitElement->setLabel('Change Logo');

    $form->setDecorators(array('FormElements',
            array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'table')), 'Form'
    ));
    //Return the form
    return $form;
}
```

ChangelogoAction

```
$form = $this->getLogoForm();
$this->view->Lform = $Lform;
```

logoupdateAction

```
$form = $this->getLogoForm();
if($form->isValid($_POST)){
    $form->logo->receive();
    $this->view->success = array('logo' => 'Logo has been changed');
} else {
    $this->view->errors = $form->getMessages();
    $this->view->form = $form;
    $this->render("changelogo");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One common problem on uploading is when enctype aren set to multipart/form-data inside the form tag.